# Why The Variable Didn't Change?

Tags: python

I try to make a calculator but when i run it it just show 0. Why my the result variable doesn't change?

```
MathSlice = list("1 + 2")
i = 0
Number1 = []
Operation = ""
Number2 = []
Result = 0
while not (str(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"):
    Number1.append(MathSlice[i])
    i += 1
Number1 = ''.join(Number1)
Operation = MathSlice[i]
while not i > len(MathSlice):
    Number2.append(MathSlice[i - 1])
    i += 1
Number2.pop(1)
Number2 = ''.join(Number2)
if Operation == "+":
    Result = int(Number1) + int(Number2)
elif Operation == "-":
    Result = int(Number1) - int(Number2)
elif Operation == "*":
    Result = int(Number1) * int(Number2)
elif Operation == "/":
    Result = int(Number1) / int(Number2)
print(Result)
```

I expect it to printing 3 but the variable result doesn't change and printing 0.

Comment: Did you account for spaces?

Comment: I know this doesn't sound important, but a tip: keep your variables lowercase: `MathSlice` should either be `math_slice` or `mathSlice`. By convention, capital letters mean a class.

Comment: Also `(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"` doesn't do what you think it does. You have to compare each individually or do `MathSlice[i] in ("+",  "-", "*",  "/")`

Comment: And learn how to debug your program by attaching a debugger or printing out your variables after each step

Comment: try don't convert string to list immediately. Split it by spaces with `.split()`. That way is easier to handle numbers with 2 or more digits

Comment: @drum first, yeah i account for space. second, thanks. third, ok i will learn:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes made:**  `while not (str(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"):` to `while not MathSlice[i] in ("+",  "-", "*",  "/"):`

**Code:**

```
MathSlice = list("1 + 2")
#print(MathSlice)
i = 0
Number1 = []
Operation = ""
Number2 = []
Result = 0
while not MathSlice[i] in ("+",  "-", "*",  "/"):
    Number1.append(MathSlice[i])
    i += 1
Number1 = ''.join(Number1)
Operation = MathSlice[i]
while not i > len(MathSlice):
    Number2.append(MathSlice[i - 1])
    i += 1
Number2.pop(1)
Number2 = ''.join(Number2)
if Operation == "+":
    Result = int(Number1) + int(Number2)
elif Operation == "-":
    Result = int(Number1) - int(Number2)
elif Operation == "*":
    Result = int(Number1) * int(Number2)
elif Operation == "/":
    Result = int(Number1) / int(Number2)
print(Result)  #3
```

Answer (score 1):

what you have done is assume that or statements only act on the second part of the evaluation, however they act on both. Basically this means you are saying is `str(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or "-" == True` etc. This then instantly cancels the while not loop as strings with characters evaluate as true in python.

The simple fix is to change your while loop from this:

```
while not (str(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"):
```

to this

```
while not str(MathSlice[i]) == "+" or str(MathSlice[i]) == "-" or str(MathSlice[i]) == "/" or str(MathSlice[i]) == "*":
```

which is unfortunately a little bit uglier but it fixes your problem :)